# Is Php reqular expression secure to insert data into database?

Tags: php, database

I'm inserting data to db with following validation where I only accept `'` and `&` and `@` and `.`. After that I'm using `mysqli_real_escape_string($var)`.

So I see it's output is :

```
I\'m a good boy &@ is it secure var for input to DB.
```

**My Questions :**

1) Is there any security issues will appear if I accept `'` and `&` and `@` and `.` ?
2) If it's not security issues then it's insert `\` to db. Is it problem to store data with backslash ?
3) If it's not a problem for security then in user panel data is showing with `\`. So is it need to escape with `stripslashes($var);`?

**My validation:**

```
$var = "I'm a good boy &@ is it secure var for input to DB.";

if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'&@ ]+$/", $var) !== 1)
    echo "var is NOT OK.<br/>";
else
    echo "var is ok.<br/>";

mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $var);
```

Comment: No need for all that when using prepared statements.

Comment: You can ignore all security problems caused by single quotes by simply using prepared statements instead of using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow! Great. One line Answer. But according to my question do you have any answer ?

Comment: As long as you're escaping the input, which you're doing now, I don't see a problem. But you're really going to like using prepared statements ;) your question would probably be best to be entered at code review though, or stack's security section.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks I accept your Answer or advise. but If I use PDO then what happened about `'` ? Will it be backslash `\` ?

Comment: Same thing. PDO has prepared statements available to use also. Using PDO on its own without prepared statements, doesn't safeguard against SQL injection. Same thing for `mysqli_`. (You're welcome).

Comment: @Fred-ii- how can I accept your answer ?

Comment: It's alright, I was happy to help.

Comment: @Niko Thanks and is there anything need to add to my regular expression to accept `'`, `.`, `&`, `@` ?

Answer (score -1):

1. Is there any security issues will appear if I accept ' and & and @ and . ?
   **There will be security issues as a single quote `(')` is used for SQL Injection**
2. If it's not security issues then it's insert \ to db. Is it problem to store data with backslash ?
   **No, there is no problem with storing the data with backslashes, that's how escaping works.**
3. If it's not a problem for security then in user panel data is showing with . So is it need to escape with stripslashes($var);?
   **Yes, it will cause a problem among display as single quotes will be escaped using a backslash, to display it without a backslash, you can use `stripslashes()`**

All these problems and questions you're mentioning can be simply ignored if you start using prepared statements as it requires no escaping whatsoever, so your database will be SQL Injection-free, there will be no backslashes making your output look bad.